# Regex to replace paragraph in MediaWiki to HTML <p> </p>

Tags: c#, php, regex, mediawiki, wiki

I need regex pattern to convert mediatext paragraph  to HTML `<p></p>`. 
Examples:

MediaWikiText:

This Example for converting paragraph in mediawiki 
==Heading== 
 Text Text Text Text Text '''Strong'''

Html:

```
<p>This Example for converting paragraph in mediawiki s ==Heading==</p>
<p><code>Text Text Text Text Text </code><strong><code>Strong</code></strong></p>
```

Comment: What is the use case here? This is tagged with both PHP and C#

Comment: How do you want the regex to know where the first paragraph ends and the second begins if all the text is in one line? What is the rule here?